# Can different laws and regulations for a ccTLD in an unfamilar country be problematic?

Tags: domain-registration, legal, domain-registrar, country-specific, country-codes

I'd like to register a `.gy` domain though this is probably applicable to others like `.me`, `.cc`, `.tv`, etc.

These are ccTLDs for countries which I am not familiar with. Should I be concerned with this given laws and regulations etc are different?

I read that there were some issues with the `.ly` domain. What dispute resolution procedures are in place for situations like this?

To be clear, I intend to use it as a personal site and operate completely within the policies of the register.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There are requirements. Here is the link: http://www.nic.py/pautas.php

You may have to translate the page. I translated it (using mouse magic and not grey matter) and here are some of the requirements.

3 Applicants

They can request the delegation of domain names under the domain PY the following:

- Individuals currently domiciled or legally residing in the Republic
  of Paraguay
- Public Law and Private persons, companies and entities of public or
  private law, established in Paraguay
- Public Law and Private persons, companies and entities of public or
  private law, established abroad, by duly authorized representatives
  constituted in Paraguay

4 The Responsible Organization

Responsible Organization is one for which a domain name is delegated. That is to say, is who actually use the domain. The applicant who is who complete the forms and performs the actions related to the delegation, may be the same Responsible Organization or may be a third party to conduct the proceedings on behalf of the Responsible Organization, which is the only practicing before the NIC's responsibility for the delegated domain.

Because of requesting the delegation of a domain name under the domain PY is understood to Responsible Organization:

- Meet the technical functioning of Domain Name System (DNS) INTERNET
  and knows the meaning of the terms used in its management.
- Expressly accepts, agrees and undertakes to comply with and abide by
  all the rules contained in this document without reservations of any
  kind.
- Disclaims any responsibility to the NIC, the Catholic University Our
  Lady of the Assumption, the LED, the National University of Asunción,
  the CNC and its officers and counselors, obligations,
  responsibilities and other acts or events that generate obligations
  applicant, giving express and advance to any legal action.

It will be the sole responsibility of the Responsible Organization which the delegated domain meets the legal regulations in force in the territory of the Republic of Paraguay and that does not infringe rights of third parties.

The NIC will have no responsibility for the use made of a domain name once delegated to the responsible organization that requested it.